# Detector for both iBeacon and Eddystone packets

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, eddystone

I'm looking for a detector which can detect both iBeacon and Eddystone packets on Raspberry pi, but I found only this code which can only detect iBeacon:
"http://www.switchdoc.com/2014/08/ibeacon-raspberry-pi-scanner-python/"
is there any detector available for this purpose? or should I implement it by myself?